# .NET: C# System.Diagnostics.Process fails to access Shared drive images if being launch as Service, but works correctly launched as a normal.exe

Tags: c#, .net, service, process

1-) I create a Python .exe which includes this code:

```
 def main():
    args = parse_arguments()
    result = []
    paths = args.files
    regions = args.regions
    oddplate = args.oddplate
    result = []


    #print ("Input args ")
    #print (args)
    #print ("\n")
    if not args.sdk_url and not args.api_key:
        raise Exception('api-key is required')
    if len(paths) == 0:
        print('File {} does not exist.'.format(args.FILE))
        return
    elif args.blur_dir and not os.path.exists(args.blur_dir):
        print('{} does not exist'.format(args.blur_dir))
        return
    ....

    print(result)
    return result
```

2-) Then, i create a c# function from .net (lets call it **ProcessFunc**), which includes this code

```
 ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    // make sure we can read the output from stdout and that window is not shown
    myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcessStartInfo.FileName = dir_app;

    // start python app with 9 arguments
    myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = " " + Iapi_key + " " + Isdk_url + " " + Iregions + " " + Iblur_amount + " " + Ioddplate + " " + Iblur_dir;

    Process myProcess = new Process();
    // assign start information to the process 
    myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
    // start the process 
    myProcess.Start();

    // Read the standard output of the app we called.  
    // in order to avoid deadlock we will read output first 
    // and then wait for process terminate: 
    StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
    string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

    /*if you need to read multiple lines, you might use: 
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd() */

    // wait exit signal from the app we called and then close it. 
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
    myProcess.Close();

    // write the output we got from python app 
    //Console.WriteLine("Value received from script: " + myString);
    return myString;
```

3-) I have 3 drives, C,N(local machine) and Z (net shared drive)

Having c# code compiled (which generates a .exe) i called the python generated .exe 2 ways:

1. Double clicking the c# .exe after introducing that code in a main program (lets call it **MyCProgramMain**)

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
   ProcessFunc();
   }
   ```

This works correctly (Iblur_dir parameter path is accepted)

2. Generating a service:

   ```
      static void Main()
        {
         System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new 
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new MyService()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
         }
   ```

Which will create a Thead:

```
public MyService()
 {
            InitializeComponent();
            HEjecucion = new Thread(classEjecucion.ProcessFunc);
                HEjecucion.Start();
```

Afterwards i will start the generated Service.

When doing it this way, i will get this message in my log (for example):

*Z:\2021-08-18\14 does not exist*

This will only happen with paths in Z:\ drive, N:\ and C:\ will be accepted.

So, when calling the Python.exe through a Main program focused generated c# .exe

`*os.path.exists(args.blur_dir)*`  understands the path exists

but if i call that same Python.exe through a Service generated with C#, it is unable to access args.blur_dir path

I have tried:

1. Creating a app.manifest in c#project which includes

(perhaps it was related to priviliges)

2. Playing around with myProcessStartInfo parameters to see if something could make

I have spent lot of time trying multiple things related to C# Process() parameters, but nothing seems to work in order to make the **Service** 'reach' the dir_blur path. ¿What else could i try?

Comment: In your services, did you try to run it "as a (local) user"? - selecting a user who actually knows what Z:\ refers to

Comment: The problem is not related to the code. It's about the service account which is the service configured to run.

Comment: If you run the app from `.exe` file. The application user is your account. But with service, you need to consider permission of service account (e.g. Local System, Network, specified account)

Comment: At a guess `Z` probably refers to a network drive, and is only accessible to your user

Comment: @Charlieface **not "probably"** (from the question: "*Z (net shared drive)*")

Comment: You may use technique described in https://superuser.com/questions/753400/map-network-drive-for-the-system-user-in-windows to map that drive for the (localsystem?) user on behalf your service runs so it will be accessible for that too.

Comment: @cly It's not a good idea. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services-and-redirected-drives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are alright guys! Problem was i was working on a remote desktop in where i was login with an specific user.

Service was automatically installed as 'Local system', and all i had to do was go to Services, in my service "properties" and in 'login' tab introduce credentials i use for remote desktop access.